# On selected drop-down change, show modal from API response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, vue.js

I'm trying to consume an API such that... via a modal, a user can enter an amount and select a payment frequency to make some payment.

I'm able to extract the various payment frequencies from the data returned and bound them to a drop-down selector.

Here is what I'm struggling to do. Based on the payment type (Especially for Weekly and Monthly ), I want that when either Weekly or Monthly options are selected i.e (onSelected),
 I want to fetch the "html:" field returned as the part for the response for those option...display the their associated html page/modal.

I'm using vue.js

Here is relevant HTML and JS Code as well as sample API response

```
<script id="depositModal_tpl" type="text/x-template">
    <div :id="modalId" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" class="modal fade bd-invest-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title w-100 text-center" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Fund Account</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="amount" class="col-form-label"><strong>Amount</strong></label>
                            <input type="text"
                                   class="form-control"
                                   id="amount"
                                   min="500"
                                   autocomplete="off"
                                   oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');"
                                   required
                                   placeholder="Enter Amount"
                                   v-model="amount">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-form-label">Frequency</label>
                            <select v-model="frequencies" id="frequency" class="form-control">
                                <option :value="null">Select Funding Frequency</option>
                                <option v-for="pm in freq" :value="pm.code" v-on:change="onFreqChange">{{pm.name}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button @@click="onSkipPayment" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Skip</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger">Invest Now</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>



    return Vue.component('deposit-mod', {
        template: "#depositModal_tpl",

        data: function () {
            return {
                accountCode: sessionStorage.getItem("accountCode"),
                amount: null,
                frequencies: Object,
                freq: []

            }
          },

        methods: {

            close() {
                $('#' + this.modalId).modal('hide')
            },

            getFrequencies: function () {

                encryptor.send("payment", "frequencies", {
                    methods: "get",

                }).then((resp) => {
                    var freqSelect = $("select#frequency");
                    this.freq = resp.data;

                    freqSelect.on("change", function () {
                        var val = $(this).val(),

                            freqq = this.frequencies.filter(function (curr) {
                                return curr.code == val;
                            })[0];


                    })


                }).catch(function (resp) {
                    utils.displayAlert(resp.message, "Could not initialize form", "red");
                });
            }

            onSkipPayment: function () {

                var loginInstance = new loginClass({
                    propsData: {

                    }
                }),
                mountPoint = document.createElement('div');
                document.body.appendChild(mountPoint)
                loginInstance.$mount(mountPoint)
            }
         },

        beforeMount: function () {
            this.modalId = 'deposit-mod' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)
            this.getFrequencies();
        },
        mounted: function () {
            $('#' + this.modalId).modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
            $('#' + this.modalId).modal('show')
        },
        destroyed: function () {
            $('#' + this.modalId).modal('hide')
        }
    });





API Repsone 


 {
     "success": true,
    "message": "Payment frequencies retrieved.",
    "data":[

 {

            "code": "D",
            "name": "Daily",
            "installmentPerYear": "366",
            "isRegular": true,
            "formFields": [],
            "disabled": false
        },
        {
            "code": "W",
            "name": "Weekly",
            "installmentPerYear": "52",
            "isRegular": true,
            "formFields": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "Day of The Week",
                    "code": null,
                    "description": "Day of The Week",
                    "multiple_values": true,
                    "regex": null,
                    "form_field_options": {
                        "tag": "input",
                        "type": "checkbox"
                    },
                    "value_options": [
                        "Monday",
                        "Tuesday",
                        "Wednesday",
                        "Thursday",
                        "Friday",
                        "Saturday",
                        "Sunday"
                    ],
                    "required": true,
                    "inheritsFrom": null,
                    "html": "<div><p><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"5__5cfd31b585824\" value=\"Monday\" id=\"5__5cfd31b585824__302343\" data-field-id=\"5__5cfd31b585824\" /><label for=\"5__5cfd31b585824__302343\">Monday</label></p><p><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"5__5cfd31b585824\" value=\"Tuesday\" id=\"5__5cfd31b585824__299225\" data-field-id=\"5__5cfd31b585824\" /><label for=\"5__5cfd31b585824__299225\">Tuesday</label></p><p><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"5__5cfd31b585824\" value=\"Wednesday\" id=\"5__5cfd31b585824__534830\" data-field-id=\"5__5cfd31b585824\" /><label for=\"5__5cfd31b585824__534830\">Wednesday</label></p><p><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"5__5cfd31b585824\" value=\"Thursday\" id=\"5__5cfd31b585824__800813\" data-field-id=\"5__5cfd31b585824\" /><label for=\"5__5cfd31b585824__800813\">Thursday</label></p><p><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"5__5cfd31b585824\" value=\"Friday\" id=\"5__5cfd31b585824__510467\" data-field-id=\"5__5cfd31b585824\" /><label for=\"5__5cfd31b585824__510467\">Friday</label></p><p><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"5__5cfd31b585824\" value=\"Saturday\" id=\"5__5cfd31b585824__539475\" data-field-id=\"5__5cfd31b585824\" /><label for=\"5__5cfd31b585824__539475\">Saturday</label></p><p><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"5__5cfd31b585824\" value=\"Sunday\" id=\"5__5cfd31b585824__232621\" data-field-id=\"5__5cfd31b585824\" /><label for=\"5__5cfd31b585824__232621\">Sunday</label></p></div>",
                    "element_id": "5__5cfd31b585824",
                    "element_name": "5__5cfd31b585824"
                }
            ],
            "disabled": false
        },

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `computed` to extract html

```
computed: {
  freqHtml() {
    if (!this.freq || !this.frequencies) {
      return ''
    }
    const item = this.freq.find(f => f.code === this.frequencies)
    if (item && item.formFields && item.formFields.length) {
      return item.formFields[0].html
    }
    return ''
  }
}
```

then inject to template using `v-html`

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label">Frequency</label>
    <select v-model="frequencies" id="frequency" class="form-control">
        <option :value="null">Select Funding Frequency</option>
        <option v-for="pm in freq" :value="pm.code" v-on:change="onFreqChange">{{pm.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <div v-html="freqHtml"></div>
</div>
```